# What causes vsprintf to throw a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, segmentation-fault, printf

I am writing a simple wrapper for syslog to make logging from my program a bit easier and allow dumping log entries to the console when selected. I have the following log function defined

```
void logDebugFunction   (int lineNumber, char* filename, const char* functionName, char* format, ...)
{
    if (LOG_DEBUG >= argPtr->logLevel)
    {
        char buffer[1000];
        char *entry;
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
        va_end(args);
        sprintf(entry, "%s:%d - %s - %s",filename, lineNumber, functionName, buffer);
        syslog(LOG_MAKEPRI(0, (LOG_DEBUG)), "%s", entry);
        if (argPtr->verbose)
        {
            // Print to stdout too
            printf( "%s", entry);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called through the following macro:

```
#define logDebug(format,...)    logDebugFunction(__LINE__, __FILE__, __func__, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

From the main function, which is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Set up syslog connection
    openlog("ARController", LOG_CONS|LOG_PID|LOG_NDELAY, LOG_DAEMON);

    // Set up our global arguments
    struct arguments arguments;
    argPtr = &arguments;

    // set default values
    arguments.verbose = 0;
    arguments.foreground = 0;
    arguments.logLevel = LOG_WARNING;

    // Send a test debug message
    logDebug("Test Debug message %d %s", 5, "a string");

    // Close our syslog connection
    closelog();
}
```

Now, when I try to run the only output I get is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, obviously not what I want.

I've done some investigation using gdb and the `--save-temps` flag to verify the following:

- In `main.i` I can see that the logDebug call in `main` has been replaced with `logDebugFunction(72, "src/main.c", __func__, "Test Debug message %d %s", 5, "a string");` which is what I'd expect to see here.
- When running, the segfault happens at the first `vsprintf` line in `logDebugFunction`
- Just before the call to `vsprintf` all the mandatory arguments of the function are correct:

  - `Breakpoint 2, logDebugFunction (lineNumber=72, filename=0x401450 "src/main.c", functionName=0x4014d3 <__func__.4035> "main", format=0x401437 "Test Debug message %d %s")`
- The `va_list` entries are what I'd expect them to be as shown by the following gdb commands ([found here](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2010-07/msg00075.html))

  - `(gdb) p *(int *)(((char*)args[0].reg_save_area)+args[0].gp_offset)
    $5 = 5`
  - `(gdb) p *(char * *)(((char*)args[0].reg_save_area)+args[0].gp_offset+8)
    $6 = 0x40142e "a string"`
- When I step into the `vsprintf` call it seems like the arguments are correct: `__IO_vsprintf (string=0x7ffffffedb40 "\200V`", format=0x401437 "Test Debug message %d %s", args=0x7ffffffedb28) at iovsprintf.c:32`

So as everything seems to be in order I'm a bit lost as to what the issue is and what steps I can take next.

Comment: Your collection of code quotes is more a puzzle than a [mcve]. Please [edit] to make helping you easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong (ignoring that there are no sanity checks) with the way you use `va_list` & `vsprintf`, so it could be that it needs more than 1000 charcaters and `buffer` is simply not large enough or your passing the argumnts in the wrong way? Have you tried using `vprintf` for debug purposes?

But I see a definitive problem in the next lines:

```
char *entry;
...
sprintf(entry, "%s:%d - %s - %s",filename, lineNumber, functionName, buffer);
```

`entry` is a unitialized pointer, pointing to nowhere. If you try to read/write through that pointer, then you get an undefined behaviour. A segfault is the result of that.

With `snprintf` you can get the length of the expression and then with `malloc` dynamically allocate memory for it (fon't forget to free it afterwards). Or you can do

```
char entry[1024];
...
sprintf(entry, "%s:%d - %s - %s",filename, lineNumber, functionName, buffer);
```

assuming that no entry will be longer than 1023 characters.

---

**EDIT** *request from the comment to elaborate on getting length from `snprintf`*

Let's start with the signature of the function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

The man page description of says:

> *man page printf(3)*
>
> The functions `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` write at most `size` bytes
>   (including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`)) to `str`.

If you want to just get the length, set `size` to 0 and `str` to NULL

```
int msglen = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, exp1, exp2, exp3,...);
```

Bear in mind that this behaviour is conform to C99. Compiling with an older compilier or older C standard might give you unspecified return value.

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how one can get the length of the formatted output using `snprintf`?

Comment: I am not saying it is incorrect, just for completeness sake.

Comment: @ajay: it's the value returned by `snprintf`.

Comment: @rici Yes, I know but the correct usage requires one to pass `0` as the second parameter which I think should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- there is no checks that format does match passed arguments (see `__attribute__ ((format (printf`);
- there are no checks that pointers are not null;
- there is no check that buffer is large enough to hold the given string (use functions taking buffer size such as `snprintf`);
- `sprintf(entry,` uses uninitialized variable `entry` instead of suitable buffer causing Undefined Behavior, attempt to write at random location pointed to by `entry` is the most likely reason for a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I encountered this when I accidentally returned in a function that was marked `_Noreturn` in a header (but not in function itself) when writing C11.

This mistake did not cause a compilation error, didn't emit a warning (with `-Wall`) and wasn't caught by neither address sanitizer (asan) or thread sanitizer (tsan), but code execution after that return was bonkers and it gave me misleading call traces.